# json parsing in android

Tags: android, json

i am getting a json response from a php host

{"uid":"0"}

i want to retrieve 0 (i.e uid value ) from it

i tried retrieving it ..but got exceptions

this is my code ..

```
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
}
finally {
    if (conn != null) {
        try {  
            conn.close ();
        }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }  
    }
}

//convert response to string
/*
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"),8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line+"\n");
    }
    is.close();
    result = sb.toString();
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
}
try
{
    ??????????????????????????
} catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [JSONOBJECT](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(src);
if (obj.has("uid")){
   String uid = obj.getString("uid");
}
```

Comment: Hi. Does this solved your problem? You need to pass the result of your webservice in place of "src".

Answer (score 0):

Using [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) makes this very easy

Comment: what if i want to send my friend's name 
i am storing name in an array 
but json_encoding method not working for this array